# Why is it so much easier to kick a basketball when it is just bouncing back from the ground?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life, collision, projectile

A basketball coach showed me that when you bounce a basketball back from the ground, it is much easier to kick it far away (actually it shoots out like a rocket), but when you want to kick it like a soccerball (dropping it on your feet from your hands), it is very hard to kick it far (actually it feels like a heavy rock breaking your leg).

I have found nothing about this on this site or the internet, except that basketballs are made of different materials so it might be something about the elasticity or how heavy it is compared to a soccer ball. Now again, the answer is not obvious I believe, and this does not work with soccer balls.

The only one I found was quora (I do not know how trustworthy that is):

[https://www.quora.com/Why-does-kicking-a-ball-that-is-rolling-towards-you-seems-to-launch-it-with-more-force-than-kicking-one-that-is-already-rolling-forwards#:~:text=Because%20it%20DOES!,and%20flies%20away%20from%20you](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-kicking-a-ball-that-is-rolling-towards-you-seems-to-launch-it-with-more-force-than-kicking-one-that-is-already-rolling-forwards#:%7E:text=Because%20it%20DOES!,and%20flies%20away%20from%20you).

Question:

1. Why is it so much easier to kick a basketball when it is just bouncing back from the ground?

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but think about what you're comparing: You're probably kicking the ball upward. Or at least, there's probably an upward component to your kick. In one case, your rising foot meets a ball that is falling toward the ground, but in the other case, it meets a ball that is rising up from the ground. Which is easier? To help something along in the direction that it already was going? or to turn it around and make it go opposite to the direction it was going?

Comment: A ball.on the ground has friction that has to be overcome when kicking. It's also a reason that golfers tee up their first shot for maximum distance.

Comment: Elastic collision with your foot where the ball contains non-zero kinetic energy, compared to if you kick it off the ground where it has zero kinetic energy.